# Extracting quoted text after a sentinel string

Tags: bash, sed

I'm looking for a sed recipe that takes as input a file and outputs a space separated list of every match of the following form:

```
sentinel-string 'stuff-to-match'
```

For instance, if the sentinel-string was "sentinel" and the file was:

```
sentinel 'match1' a random ' I don't know and maybe a sentinel 'match2' ''' test
```

I want the output to be:
match1 match2

I've been trying to construct this for a bit now and I'm just not familiar enough with the utilities to get the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try grep in this way:

```
s="sentinel"  
 grep -Po "(?<=$s ')[^']*" inputFile|tr '\n' ' '
```

variable `s` stores the pattern string, in your case, it is the sentinel-string.

Answer (score 2):

`Sed` is not the tool for editing a line, but here you have one way:

```
sed -e "
  s/sentinel[ ]*/\n/g
  s/[^\n]*\n'\([^']*\)'[^\n]*/\1 /g
" infile
```

How does it work?

```
s/sentinel[ ]*/\n/g
```

Inserts a newline character just before the word to extract. So input would be like:

```
<blank line>
'match1' a random ' I don't know and maybe a 
'match2' ''' test
```

And

```
`s/[^\n]*\n'\([^']*\)'[^\n]*/\1 /g`
```

extracts what is after those newlines characters, removing everything else.

It yields:

```
match1 match2
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - but I'm not sure what you mean when you say that sed is not the tool for editing a line. I thought sed was a stream editor - how is this different?

Comment: In my opinion, `sed` is the right tool to do simple changes on group of lines. Compare it with `awk` that without any effort splits the line in spaces and lets you access any of them, or `perl` (`grep` too) and their powerful regexps with look-aheads and look-behinds. They are much much better than `sed` to do "complex" modifications to a single line.

Comment: Okay. Now I understand what you mean.

Comment: Nice solution. Lines that do not contain `sentinel` need to be skipped still and `\n` as a placeholder works only in GNU sed. Instead of `\n` you could use another character for example `§`. Then it would become: `sed '/sentinel */!d;'"s//§/g; s/[^§]*§'\([^']*\)'[^§]*/\1 /g" infile` I agree sed is not the best tool for this ;)

Comment: @Scrutinizer: Yes, your command is more accurate and useful for non-GNU users of `sed` but although that character is strange, the newline is the only one that you can absolutely sure will not appear in the line.